# Wifi solution to connect two warehouses on to same network

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11, lan

I’ve just acquired a second warehouse however it’s approx 100m from my current one.

To save me the headache of having two wifi systems what’s the best solution to bring my current wifi network into my new warehouse? They’re not overly large warehouses so I don’t need to start bringing in professionals to do it as that would be a bit ott.

Install an Ethernet cable from one building to the other? Note the two warehouses are inside the same building so wiring a cable would be fairly straight forward

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Given the distance of approximately 100 m, you should use fiber for extending your network. Then add another WAP using the same SSID but a different radio channel (with at least two channels in between for 2.4 GHz).

Comment: Fiber is a good idea and not too difficult with decent switches. I would suggest simply using a different SSID on the second WiFi network so you can easily tell which you are connected to. If you have a good managed WiFi solution, it is easy to configure them so coverage is good in both locations but doesn't overlap. If you use very basic WiFi access points, it is harder to tweak things to achieve that so a separate SSID can sometimes make it easier to live with.

Answer (score 0):

Zac67 suggested a fiber run, and that is a good answer if the building will grow to need a larger network there in the future and you can facilitate the cost.

However if you need a lower cost alternative then you could consider a point to point Wi-Fi bridge, Ubiquiti comes to mind for a cheap solution, or Aruba for a enterprise solution. This would mean you could have the same Wi-Fi network, with the same SSID and subnet.

Note, you mentioned the that the run would be about 100M, you *could* run an ethernet cable, however note that the theortical maximum (and standard for 1000BASE-T) is 100M, so you would most probably need a switch/hub/repeater, in reality if you wanted unaffected performance 88M is as much as you would want to go.

Comment: An additional (quality) switch/duplex repeater/extender is not likely to cost (much) less than a simple fiber run and it does increase complexity - I'd try to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Single Mode Fiber/SMF would be cheaper than 2 Ubiquiti. Just make sure the switches at both ends have a SFP slot. the SMF SFP module is ~$40,x2 is $80. The SMF cable (yellow), 100M is ~$40 as well. If your switch doesn't support SFP modules, you will need to purchase SFP/Ethernet adapter, just upgrade. you can find 10G L2 Switches under $500 w/SFP modules. The project shouldn't cost more that $1K all in. Don't forget the Cheetos...